# Average of a function over random uniform sample.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I'm trying to understand some implications concerning the Weak Laws of Large Numbers, and I'm stuck in this problem.

If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function with $\int_0^1\mid f(x)\mid dx<\infty$ and $U_1,...,U_n,...$ is a sequence of independent uniformly distributed random variables, consider the following average:

\begin{equation}
I_n = \frac{f(U_1) + ... + f(U_n)}{n}
\end{equation}

Then, $I_n\to \int_0^1f(x)dx$ in probability.

I was trying to apply some kind of Weak Law of Large Numbers, since we can compute using the uniform distribution that:

\begin{equation}
E[f(U_j)] = \int_0^1f(x)dx
\end{equation}

And hence:

\begin{equation}
E[I_n] = I
\end{equation}

However, I was not able to get some bound on the variance $var[f(U_j)]$ in order to apply the Weak Law of Large Numbers.

So instead I also tried to prove $L^1$ convergence, but got stuck as well: assume $I=0$ wlog, and then I got the following chain of inequalities:

\begin{equation}
E[\mid I_n \mid] \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}E[\mid f(U_j)\mid] = \int_0^1 \mid f(x) \mid dx < \infty
\end{equation}

Which is far for enough to prove $L^1$ convergence. When trying to estimate the actual probability convergence, I had no luck either, since my only idea was to use Chebyshev's Inequality, which would be useful only if I knew about some $L^p$ convergence.

What would be a better approach here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: recall that simple functions are dense in $L^1,$ so it is enough to prove the result for the indicator function of an interval $[a, b].$

Comment: So, with this approach we could conclude directly that, if $f$ is the indicator function of an interval, then $var[f(U_j)]\leq C<\infty$ for all $j$, and by the Weak Law we could conclude not only convergence in probability, but convergence in $L^2$ (which is stronger by Chebyshev). Does this imply that we have not only $I_n \to \int_0^1 f$ in probability for all $f\in L^1$ but also this convergence holds in $L^2$? Furthermore, why it is enough to consider indicator functions of intervals? I would guess this follows from some use of the monotone class lemma.